# How to count how many times a name appears against months over multiple Excel sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet where I have multiple sheets for different locations and in each location sheet I have names and months. (column B is the name and column C shows different months)

On the main sheet I want to create a list of how many times a name appears against each month, so for example how many times does the name Ben appear against October.

Can this be done using formulas? or would it be a pivot table?

Comment: Is the month a "Oct" text or a excel date formatted?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like as a starting point.

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"oct",B:B,"ben")
```

the countifs counts the row if all conditions are met. So only if ben is in column B AND oct is in column C.

You can get more fancy adding cell references for the month and name, or putting your data in a table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

complementing gns100's answer, you can use the '*' character to select names more easily, if you have only part of the name.

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"oct",B:B,"*ben*")
```